# Laravel - Need specific name of files and folders with storage function

Tags: php, laravel

i have a form with slug, input files, etc.

I need if i put por example in form:

`slug = hello-how-are-you`

`file = header.png`

`file2 = home.png`

`Laravel` create me a folder in storage like this: `/projects/hello-how-are-you` with the `header.png` and `home.png`.

I try it but can't do it.. i try with something like this:

```
public function storeProject(Request $request)
{
    $project = new Project();
    $project->slug = $request->input("slug");
    $namefolder = $project->slug;
    $project->position = $request->input("position");
    $project->public = $request->input("public");
    $header = $request->file('pathheader');
    $home = $request->file('pathhome');
    $project->pathheader = $header;
    $project->pathhome = $home;
    \Storage::disk('projects')->put('header.png', \File::get($header));
    $project->save();
}
```

In filesystem i have this:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    'projects' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path() . '/projects',
    ],
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],
```

*SOLVED!*
Thanks to @Dees040
If want smash the name of the file and do it without a foreach, you can do it like this:

```
public function storeProject(Request $request)
        {
        $project = new Project();
        $project->slug = $request->input("slug");
        $project->position = $request->input("position");
        $project->public = $request->input("public");
        $project->pathheader = $request->file('pathheader');
        $project->pathhome = $request->file('pathhome');
        \Storage::disk('projects')->makeDirectory($project->slug);
        \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathheader,'header.png');
        \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathhome,'home.png');
        $project->save();
        }
```

Comment: Does `\Storage::disk('projects')->put($project->slug."/header.png")` work?

Comment: @apokryfos no mate, if i do that the files name will be hello-how-are-youheader.png hahah

Comment: So something is swallowing the slash?

Comment: No, storage::disk work with first the 'disks' on the filesystems.php (in my case is projects), and after put goes the name of the file so if you put $project->slug this will be the name of the file

Comment: Have you actually tried it and it didn't work? `$project->slug."/header.png"‌` is meant to be the full path relative to your disk root. That includes a directory name and file name.

Comment: If i put  `\Storage::disk('projects')->put($project->slug."/header.png"‌​)` the syntax is not correct, i guess i should pass the file to, and if i do this: `    \Storage::disk('projects')->put($project->slug."/header.png", $header‌​);` i take undefined variable header.

Comment: How about `\Storage::disk('projects')->put($project->slug."/header.png"‌, \File::get($header));` ?

Comment: Incorrect syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you:

```
public function storeProject(Request $request)
{
    $project = Project::create($request->only('slug', 'position', 'public', 'pathheader', 'pathhome'));

    \Storage::disk('projects')->makeDirectory($project->slug);

    foreach ($request->allFiles() as $file) {
        \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug, $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dees040 if i make this, the directory is created good but the name of the file is something like: aisudadljlasiuaiosdiaosp328ralka.png , i try it this before.. know how to set a specific name?

Comment: Thanks mate. It works. I do it a bit different cause i'm not who will use the app so i prefer to smash the name of the file so where you put $file->getClientoriginalName() i put 'header.png' or 'home.png'. Know how to do it with foreach? I think it's better without. Thanks anyway, +1 !

Comment: Yeah, you can totally do it without a foreach. I'm glad it helped! You can mark this answer as solution, so that it can help other people. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Create the directory first:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('projects')->makeDirectory($namefolder);
```

And then, store the files:

```
$project->pathheader = Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($namefolder, $header, $header->getClientOriginalName());
$project->pathhome = Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($namefolder, $home, $home->getClientOriginalName());
```

Comment: If i do that, projects folder is not created and the name of the file is aosidasdadla23232das.png ..

Comment: I forgot to choose the disk, and if you don't want the generated unique ID, you can replace `putFile` with `putFileAs` I have updated my answer.